# Apache Tomcat and Spring MVC working with javascript library on a view

Tags: javascript, web-services, tomcat, spring-mvc, d3.js

After I do a Tomcat deployment

```
<deployed root, say, url= foo.com>
|
|---js
|     |__ d3.v3.min.js
|
|
|---foo.jsp
```

`foo.jsp` is like,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/js/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script> 
...
    </head>
<body>
     ... //using d3.js library here
</body>
<html>
```

My code works when directly pointing `d3.js` on their website. However, it doesn't work if it is on my local project directory.

As it is a Spring MVC+Tomcat, `foo.com/js/d3.v3.min.js` would be a 404 error. In Spring MVC, all the requests to a URL are handled by a controller. Do I need a controller and view only for this js file?  Or do I need to configure something so that JSP file can use the JS library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you map /* to DispatcherServlet

if yes try

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
```

Comment: I did exactly this, it is very close! However, tomcat maps the the js URL to foo.com/js/d3.v3.min.js/, notice there is one more '/' at the end. Do you have any idea how can I get rid of the last '/' in the URL? Thanks!

Comment: I found the reason, I created a controller for that URL, so your answer is perfect! Thanks!